# Winograd's DFT of prime power, size 27 (3^3) needed

Tags: fft, dft

I need to derive code - or preferably see code of already derived - for Winograd's prime power DFT of size 27.

Found the [original (1978) paper](https://www.ams.org/mcom/1978-32-141/S0025-5718-1978-0468306-4/S0025-5718-1978-0468306-4.pdf), but lack the background in number theory etc to be able to follow the process.

Also failed to Google for ready made solution.

No, it isn't a study assignment...

Comment: it's been a while for me as well, so I don't think I'll find the code. And much less, the theory. Anyways, IIRC, for small primes such as 3, you'd never use Winograd, but always use radix-p Cooley-Tukey. Are you sure you want to use Winograd?

Comment: Winograd's prime power method doesn't need (if I understood correctly) twiddle factors between sub-DFTs. My target is HW, where multiplications are much more expensive compared to additions, thus I am trying to find a formula minimizing MUL usage.

The original paper is here:

https://www.ams.org/mcom/1978-32-141/S0025-5718-1978-0468306-4/S0025-5718-1978-0468306-4.pdf

Comment: 27 = 3*3*3. So it seems doing three stages of a radix 3 DFT seems the way to go here. The radix 3 twiddler factors are 1 and $( 1 \pm j\sqrt{3})/2$ so you only need to multiply with $\sqrt(3)$. I don't think there is more efficient way of doing this

Comment: May I suggest this other reference? I.W. Selesnick; C.S. Burru "Automatic generation of prime length FFT programs", 1996
https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/pubs/FFTPrimeTSP.pdf